# Reusing result of dispatch_get_main_queue() / dispatch_get_global_queue() is safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, asynchronous, swift

I have this simple async code.

```
class MyClass {
    func myFunc() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            // some background work
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               // foreground work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering, can we rewrite this like this?

```
let background_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
let main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

class MyClass {
    func myFunc() {
        dispatch_async(background_queue) {
            // some background work
            dispatch_async(main_queue) {
               // foreground work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring (lazy) global variables that cache `dispatch_get_global_queue()` or `dispatch_get_main_queue()` result and reusing them.

Apparently it works as expected, but because all codes I've ever seen uses `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_???_queue(` idiom, I thought it's possibly unsafe?

What I would like to know is: **Is this guaranteed to be safe?**

Comment: XCode offers a handy snippet for dispatch_async that prepopulates this. I think it's generally left as-is because why bother changing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `dispatch_get_main_queue()` and `dispatch_get_global_queue()` for a given priority will always return the same queue. You are free to save these values for your convenience. Calling `dispatch_get_???_queue` right at the point of use is common, but isn't really an idiom. There just often isn't any reason to create an extra variable.

From the docs for `dispatch_get_main_queue()`:

> Returns the serial dispatch queue associated with the application’s main thread.

There is exactly one of these.

From the docs for `dispatch_get_global_queue()`:

> Returns a system-defined global concurrent queue with the specified quality of service class.

This doesn't technically promise that there is exactly one queue at each level (though there is), but that doesn't matter for global queues (since you can't modify them). These queues do exist for the entire run of the program.